# Xcode Cocos 2D How To Use Selector With Multiple Parameters

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, selector

I am trying to do something like this:

```
CCMenuItemImage *BuyButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Buy.jpg" selectedImage:@"Buy.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(Function:cnt)];
```

For some reason I can't pass any parameters to the function 'Function'. I have spend a lot of  time looking into this but the the only solution i have found uses object ids and i would rather not get into that. This button is in a loop so i can't just have another function called thats get parameters from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+ (id)itemWithNormalImage:selectedImage:target:selector:` does not support selectors with parameters. If you want to perform a selector that takes arguments, you can use `+ (id)itemWithNormalImage:selectedImage:block:` instead. In the block just run any code you want:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Buy.jpg" selectedImage:@"Buy.jpg" block:^(id sender) {
    [weakSelf methodWithParameterOne:one two:two];
}];
```

Comment: In that case you should accept the answer. See the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send parameters by `selectors` by colons.

The typical example is :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethodWithObject:) withObject:myObject];
```

Which calls

```
- (void)myMethodWithObject:(id)object;
```

Similarly you need to do like above, may be as :

```
CCMenuItemImage *BuyButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Buy.jpg" selectedImage:@"Buy.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(Function:) withObject:cnt];
```

You need to change the Function by:

```
-(void)FunctionWithCnt:(<type>)cntObject;
```

and then use `@selector(FunctionWithCnt:)`

Comment: This code doesn't work, this is a cocos 2d function, im not sure why it wouldn't work.         CCMenuItemImage *BuyButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Buy.jpg" selectedImage:@"Buy.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(BuyTruck:) withObject:Truck];

Comment: No, it doesn't look good. That method simply doesn't exist in cocos2d.